# How to find entries that are not related?

Tags: relations

Is there a simple way to find entries that do not have a relationship with another channel? I see similar questions [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/603/how-to-find-entries-with-no-category) and [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/739/displaying-entries-that-are-not-related/766#766), but neither seem to work in this context (or I don't know how to adapt their answers).

I have 3 channels, 'accounts', 'clubs' and 'subscriptions'. Every 'subscription' has a required entries field (limit 1) for 'account' and 'club'. In this case, I'm trying to find 'accounts' that are not associated with a club (i.e. do not have a 'subscription'). Sounds like it should be easy, but not finding an answer.

Looking for something like `{% set params = params | merge({ not relatedTo : subscriptions }) %}`, which obviously doesn't work. I'm using merge because there may be other criteria as well (such as account status, etc).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to approach this in two steps:

1. Get all the entries that DO have relationships.
2. Filter those entries out of your ElementCriteriaModel, either by using the "not" syntax on the entries `id` parameter of the `craft.entries` variable, or by using the `without` Twig filter in your loop source.